# Does anyone know Flex-like (pure) ActionScript3 DropDownList and/or DataGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

We are rewriting our multiscreen game from *Flex Project* to *ActionScript Mobile Project* (root object is `flash.display.Sprite` and not `spark.components.Application`)

Aim is to increase performance on tablets and have better overview what exactly is going on, what listeners are added and so. (I just don't trust Flex in this.)

Do you know any alternative for `DropDownList` and/or `DataGrid`?

I would be very grateful, thanks.

T.

EDIT#1:
I can't use MinimalComps, because there are little options to customize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Flex Framework is built in pure ActionScript; so the phrasing of your question is a bit odd.  I think you really mean to ask if there is a more "lightweight/performant" ActionScript3 component set than the Flex Framework.

There are a few alternative component sets:

- [MinimalComps](http://www.minimalcomps.com/)
- [Reflex](http://reflexplatform.com/)
- [Flight Stealth](http://jacwright.com/66/flight-stealth-a-flex-component-alternative/)

MinimalComps and Reflex are the two big ones.  I think the Flight Stealth thing is a branch of Reflex.  I thought there was a third major alterantive; but the name escapes me and googling didn't jog my memory.

Of course, it's always a trade off with any component set.  I know that MinimalComps has been criticized for it's lack of styling, for example.

I have found the Mobile Optimized Flex Framework 4.5 to be very performant on my Galaxy Tab and Xoom.  We have a mobile optimized DropDownList coming out as a Flextras component before the end of the month; it is 100% AS3; however does have dependencies to the Flex Framework.

In terms of DataGrid; I'm not sure.  DataGrid's aren't really designed for mobile use and they fall apart' on the smaller screen.  I'm not sure if that will change.

Comment: Thanks. Simple requirement but with huge consequences - root of app is just Spite, not flex Application. If I could I would use just DropDownList from Flex, but I didn't got it work on root Sprite object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it has the components you seek, but [minimalcomps](https://github.com/minimalcomps/minimalcomps) are nice and simple.